# Dock and top bar blinking/flashing at fullscreen

Tags: 20.04, gnome-shell, ubuntu-gnome, gnome-shell-extension, dock

The dock is flashing (opening and closing) when I have smart hide mode
enabled (Dash to Dock extension). The same phenomenon occurs when I
use the "Hide Top Bar" extension with hidden mode and the default ubuntu dock...

The blinks occur with a certain pattern, which I believe is based on
the values of the extensions (pressure setting etc.) ... Anyway, it is
a problem that affects three different extensions at the same time.
Usually the problem starts when I use Firefox's fullscreen. Sometimes
the dock and the top bar work perfectly, but after a while they start
to blink. You can click on the icons, but you need to reach the
correct timing. If it blinks too fast, it becomes very difficult to
use the dock in full screen.

The problem happens only in some windows (which were used in
fullscreen mode) and do not reach other windows. It is resolved with
the closing and reopening of the program, but soon they reappear...

This is the only problem that is destroying my experience with Ubuntu. I would be grateful if anyone is able to assist me...

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by reset in Tweak Tools.

Comment: how did you solve the issue?